# Retrieving and scraping large amounts of data from third party websites

Tags: php, mysql

OI want to retrieve and scrape large amounts of data about users from a third party website. Once the person logs in, I get their data from the third party website and scrape it. How do I do this most effectively as to prevent a significant load on the server and to make sure pages don't load too slow? I was thinking of setting up a background process that retrieves the data and setting the process to low priority. Do you guys have other tips for me?

I'm using PHP and Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

[Data Scraping - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping)

Is this the Data Scraping you are talking about? If yes, we will probably need more details to be able to help.

- How do you know, a user logged in?
- What kind of access do you have to the 3rd party system?

Comment: Basically I want to get a lot of data from Twitter about the user. I was just wondering what the effective way of doing that was without slowing the pages down and producing effective load. I was thinking of having the user log in, and afterwards having a background process with low priority getting the data needed about the user since its a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accurately answer, more information is needed. To point you in the correct direction, you should use cURL to load the webpage into a string. Then use PHPs DOM parser to parse the page. If you are looking for specific elements in the page, DOM XPATH queries will be useful (http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). Alternatively, you can load the page directly using DOM->LoadHTML() but there are far less options.